# Twitter REST API call using oauth_consumer_key not working

Tags: ios, twitter

I have the following REST API call to twitter. I am passing in my_oauth_consumer_key that I have from twitter after registering.

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=verge&count=19&oauth_consumer_key=<my_oauth_consumer_key>
```

However, I am getting the following return object

```
{
errors: [
{
code: 215,
message: "Bad Authentication data."
}
]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?